# Вывод матрицы на форму

Tags: winforms, c#

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача, вывести матрицу на форму(двумерный массив) через C# WinForms. Сейчас думаю каким способом это проще всего сделать. Есть на примете контрол ListBox, но я не знаю будет ли он корректно отображать её.

Имеется ввиду стандартная матрица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**На мой взгляд, самым простым и в то же время наиболее функциональным будет сочетание DataTable вместе с DataGridView.**

> Сразу же вижу потенциальную проблему в
> том, что DataGridView автоматически не
> будет добавлять / удалять колонки у
> матрицы при изменении данных,
> потребуется реализовывать это вручную.

Ничего подобного, при таком коде:

```
DataTable matrix = new DataTable("Матрица");
...
//загоняем матрицу в matrix
...
dataGridView.DataSource = matrix; 
/* этой строчкой теперь все изменения dataGridView
   будут отражаться в matrix */
```

И если на форму добавить, к примеру, TextBox и Button для добавления нового столбца, то реализация нажатия кнопки будет следующая:

```
matrix.Columns.Add(textBox.Text, typeof(int));
dataGridView.Update();
```

И новая колонка будет добавлена в matrix.
Более того, в силу своего утверждения о функциональности, можно сохранить эту матрицу в файл одной строчкой:

```
matrix.WriteXml("Matrix.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

И также одной строчкой загрузить при необходимости...

Answer (score 1):

Специально для матричных данных у DevExpress есть компонент PivotGrid. Но он платный.

Если собираетесь ограничиться стандартными компонентами WindowsForms, рекомендую либо использовать DataTable, либо вручную реализовать в своей матрице IList и ITypedList, чтобы представлять строки и колонки как динамические множества. Сразу же вижу потенциальную проблему в том, что DataGridView автоматически не будет добавлять / удалять колонки у матрицы при изменении данных, потребуется реализовывать это вручную.

Answer (score 0):

В Forms есть готовый компонент [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx). Это самый подходящий вариант. Правда, компонент достаточно мощный и его настройка потребует некоторых усилий.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой выриант использовать TextBox, выставив свойство MultiLine = True. А потом к свойству Text добавлять строки матрицы.